# Why is the number of links to my site in Google Search Console getting lower?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, backlinks, link-building

My site's link number was about 4000+ about 3 weeks ago. Now it's getting lower and lower day by day.  Today it's about 2300.

I have started link bulding by registering my site in different web and blog directories, forums, Q&A sites, popular websites, etc. I expected to see a positive result, the number should have gone up. But now it's getting lower.

What shall I do?

Comment: "I expected to see a positive result" - NO!   That type of link building is very spammy.  You can create some links to your site from other sites you control.   You can also request links from very related sites.   Putting your link on the types of sites you have been targeting is much more likely to get your site penalized that for Google to recognize the links and report them to you in search console.

Answer (score 1):

I think you created maximum backlinks using comments. Google may have crawled these backlinks from the "recent comments" sidebar from those pages. The sidebar appears on appx. each page of these websites. So google crawled all these backlinks. Now after few days, when new comments have been added to the same website, your backlink stopped showing on this "recent comments section". That's the reason your backlinks got reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that the number of backlink to your website are reducing. Either your submissions for backlinks are been pulldown by the respective websites.

Or else the number of 404 error pages have increase. 
Please check any soft error are present in the console

Comment: I checked the errors, and seems the problem is not connected with it. Probably, the websites where I am registered are shutting down. But why is it happening so suddenly and all together?